# The type or namespace name 'Vector<double>' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Numerics'

Tags: .net, system.numerics

I tried to use [`System.Numerics.Vector<double>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn858385(v=vs.111).aspx) in my code but got a build error

> The type or namespace name 'Vector' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Numerics'

Am I missing an assembly reference?

My csproj targets .NET 4.6.1

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>

<Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
<Reference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors" />
```

[image]

Other types appear correctly

[image]

Comment: IntelliSense is not lying to you.  You must add the [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Numerics.Vectors/) to get the risky types.

Comment: Thanks Hans, let me try that. MSDN doesn't explain at all https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics(v=vs.111).aspx

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the [ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) method, for instance, the MSDN shows the .NET version in the top. But for [Vector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn858385(v=vs.111).aspx), strangely, it does not. It might have been moved from the .NET framework to the Nuget repository and MS kept the MSDN document without saying anything about it.

Anyway, if you make sure you are using the `4.6.1 runtime` (it does not work on 4.5.1 and 4.5.2), just install [this nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Numerics.Vectors/), it works fine.

[image]

Comment: Probably because those types exist in the framework itself, not in the add-on [Numerics.Vectors](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Numerics.Vectors/) package.  I agree that MSDN could be more clear on that fact.